# Prove that there is no unbiased estimator for $1/ \theta$ when we have one observation from $U(0,\theta)$.

Tags: statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, estimation

If we have a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ from $U(0,\theta)$, then it can be proved that
for $\frac{1}{\theta}$, an unbiased estimator is $\frac{n-1}{nX_{(n)}}$, where $X_{(n)}:=\max(X_1,...,X_n)$, which is also sufficient and complete and has density $n \theta^{-n}t^{n-1}$. Therefore, for $n=1$, there is no unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\theta}$. Is there an alternative proof for the non-existence of an unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\theta}$ when $n=1$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This makes no sense as written. You claim that a certain unbiased estimator exists, given by an expression that's undefined for $n=1$, and then you conclude from that that no unbiased estimator exists for $n=1$. A somewhat similar argument that would be logically valid (I don't know whether the premise is true) would be: It can be proved that if an unbiased estimator exists, it must have this form. Since this form isn't defined for $n=1$, no unbiased estimator for $n=1$ exists. Is that what you were trying to say?

Comment: Yes, however and in order to prove the existence of the estimator, i started from a random sample. I  want to prove that there is no unbiased estimator for $1/ \theta$ when $n=1$ without taking into account the existing estimator when a random sample is given.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the expression $\frac{n-1}{nX_{(n)}}$ is undefined for $n = 1$. Unless $X_{(n)} = 0$ this expression should evaluate to $0$ for $n = 1$. Is it possible that the correct formula for the estimator is actually the **reciprocal** of this expression? In that case, the estimator would be undefined for $n = 1$ due to division by $0$.